# jQuery $('element').one() event call from multiple locations

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have some modal that has strange behavior on second open, it call .one() event from location that I did not expecting.

When first time clicking `.modal-trigger` all goes fine, same with clicking `.close-modal, .modal-sandbox`. But whe I clicking `.modal-trigger` again, jQuery calling callback from `modalBox.one('animationend transitionend')`;

```
$(".modal-trigger").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let modalWindow = $($(this).attr("href"));
    let modalBox = modalWindow.find('.modal-box');
    let sidebarWidth = $aside.width();

    $("body").css({"overflow-y": "hidden"}).addClass('blurred');

    if ($(window).width() >= 992) {
       modalBox.css({"margin-left": `${sidebarWidth}px`});
    }

    animateCSS(modalWindow, 'showing', function (element) {
        element.addClass('show').removeClass('showing');
        modalBox.addClass('show');
    });
});

 $(".close-modal, .modal-sandbox").on('click', function () {
    let modalWindow = $(this).closest('.modal');
    let modalBox = modalWindow.find('.modal-box');

    modalBox.one('animationend transitionend', function () {
        modalBox.removeAttr('style');
        modalWindow.removeClass('show');
        $("body").css({"overflow-y": "auto"}).removeClass('blurred');
    });

    modalBox.removeClass('show');
});

function animateCSS(element, animationName, callback) {
    element = $(element);
    element.addClass(animationName);

    function handleAnimationEnd() {
        element.removeClass(animationName);

        if (typeof callback === 'function') callback(element);
   }

    element.one('animationend transitionend', handleAnimationEnd);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `one()` more than once...it will run once per call.

Add the listener then remove it using `off()`

```
 modalBox.on('animationend transitionend', function () {
    modalBox.removeAttr('style');
    modalWindow.removeClass('show');
    $("body").css({"overflow-y": "auto"}).removeClass('blurred');
    // remove listener
    modalBox.off('animationend transitionend')

});
```

Comment: Why it should run more than once if I calling `boxModal.one()` only inside click event and then it should be removed automatically until new `$(".close-modal, .modal-sandbox").on('click')` call?